# Riemann curvature tensor on surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

I am trying to get a geometric interpretation of the riemann curvature tensor for 2-dimensional surfaces:
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
In https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor we can find the following equality:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt} \tau_{sX} ^{-1} \tau_{tY}^{-1}\tau_{sX} \tau_{sY} \Big|_{s=t=0}=R(X,Y)Z$$
Where I can get the proof of the last statement?

Many thanks!

Comment: This http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/visualcurvature.pdf may help,

Comment: Just compute it directly by hand using the displayed equation two lines above the one you are referring to. // There's also a typo in your version, the last $\tau_{sY}$ should probably be $\tau_{tY}$.

Comment: Have you understood that $\tau_{sX} ^{-1} \tau_{tY}^{-1}\tau_{sX} \tau_{sY}$ describes a "transportation" along something that looks like a rectangle (at least when $s$ small) that doesn't close ? The infinitesimal "trend of non-closedness" (!!!) is captured by the limit when $t$ and $s$ tend to $0$ (see the illustration on the Wikipedia article).

Comment: Maybe my problem is the notation. How is defined $\tau_{sX}$? Something like $\tau_{sX}: (¿?)\to(¿?)$

Comment: This problem is discussed in some detail in section 11.4 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, Gravitation and Cosmology.

Comment: The notation $\tau_{sX}$ means a linear operator on vector fields, defined perhaps not on all vector fields, associating to each vector field $Y$ the vector field $\tau_{sX} Y$ whose value at each point $m \in M$ of your manifold $M$ is the vector given by parallel transporting $Y$ from the point $e^{-tX}m$ along the flow line of $X$ to the point $m$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are stating is meaning, that if you take a vector $v$ at some $p\in M$ and you parallel transport it along a rectangle on a two-dimensional surface in $M$ the resulting deviation for the limit of a vanishing rectangle is exactly what one defines as "curvature". For an explicit calculation leading to this interpretation of Curvature I refer you to read the second and third chapter of

R. Wald, *General Relativity*, Chicago University Press, 1984